# Is my .fla file destroyed?

Tags: flash-cs5.5

I am using flash cs5.5

While saving the fla file my computer froze, and I had to shut down the program. 
Now I am trying to get back into the file and it wont open...

Is everything I have done lost forever??

and I cant get any movieclips out...

I think I am going to get fired. This is going to be very bad if I cannot recover the file somehow.

Comment: Backups is a very good thing!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

[How to Recover a Corrupt Flash CS5.5/CS6 FLA File](http://www.daffodilistic.com/2011/08/24/how-to-recover-a-corrupted-flash-cs5-5-fla-file/)

Comment: How can you do backups in flash? It forces you to overwrite every time you compile.